# dealing with a quiz script, need to calculate results via php, having problems with searching $_POST's

Tags: php

On this system a user can create a quiz of any number of questions, that info saves to a database. I'm using the below to output the quiz to the users. This outputs fine and you can only choose one of each answer. Each question has 3 inputs with the same post name, q1 has ans1 ans1 ans1, q2 has ans2ans2 ans2 etc... thats where the ".$x." comes in.

```
    $x = 1;
    while($row = mysql_fetch_row($quiz)) {
        echo "Question ".$x.": ";
        echo "<a><b> $row['question'] </b></a>";
        echo "<input type='radio' name='ans".$x." /> ".$row['ans1']."<br />";
        echo "<input type='radio' name='ans".$x." /> ".$row['ans2']."<br />";
        echo "<input type='radio' name='ans".$x." /> ".$row['ans3']."<br />";
        $x = $x + 1;
    }
```

The problem is in the next php page. I'm trying to loop through all posts and where the post matches the correct ans then result = result + 1. I need a loop that does something like this:

```
$x = 1;
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($quiz)) {
    if ($_POST[ans[$x]]=='$row['correct']' { $result = $result + 1; 
    }
    $x = $x + 1;
    }
```

is there a way i can use a variable in that $_POST value to say ans1 ans2 for each loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$x = 1;
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($quiz)) {
    if ($_POST['ans'.$x] == $row['correct']) { $result = $result + 1; }
    $x = $x + 1;
}
```

Hope this will solve your problem

Comment: mate this was it! I also forgot to assign values to the radio inputs which I've done now, but the ['ans'.$x] you provided was the key syntax to get it working! good man!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
$x = 1;
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($quiz)) {
    echo "Question ".$x.": ";
    echo "<a><b> $row['question'] </b></a>";
    echo "<input type='radio' name='ans[".$row['ansId']."][".$x."] ' /> ".$row['ans1']."<br />";
    echo "<input type='radio' name='ans[".$row['ansId']."][".$x."] ' /> ".$row['ans2']."<br />";
    echo "<input type='radio' name='ans[".$row['ansId']."][".$x."] ' /> ".$row['ans3']."<br />";
    $x = $x + 1;
}
```

Your front script:

```
$x = 1;
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($quiz)) {
if ($_POST['ans'][$row['ansId']][$x]=='$row['correct']' { 
    $result = $result + 1; 
}
$x = $x + 1;
}
```

Comment: got it working with the other comment. cheers for the help though.